# map int over 2D array python

Tags: python, numpy, parsing, multidimensional-array

To parse

```
s="1,2,3,4_5,6,7,8"
```

as `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]`

I am currently using

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([list(map(int,r.split(","))) for r in s.split("_")])
```

Is there a more pythonic or one-shot inbuilt way of doing this or am I on the right track here?
Python newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list-comprehensions:

```
s="1,2,3,4_5,6,7,8"

a = np.array([[int(x) for x in r.split(',')] for r in s.split('_')])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.genfromtxt`:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

s="1,2,3,4_5,6,7,8"

np.genfromtxt(StringIO(s.replace("_", "\n")), delimiter=",")

array([[1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [5., 6., 7., 8.]])
```

Comment: Ah nice answer! Why is `StringIO` necessary here?

Comment: `genfromtxt` reads from a file-like object, which `StringIO` provides.